# Trigger C# code from the network using PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I'm working on a project where I have to trigger my windows desktop app to fetch the database for new rows once a user on the internal network send new requests.

I have managed to hack this around through several ways:

1. A timer on the C# desktop app with half a second interval.
2. The PHP webapp creates an XML file with the requests on the OS where the C# app is hosted then the File System Watcher class does the job.
3. SOAP PHP web service and consume it in C#.

Is there a clean direct way to do this? because I don't like any of the hacks I did as it's full of bugs.

Comment: "Full of bugs" is a bit vague.  Option 1 is as sensible as anything else, and has the virtue of simplicity.  What's the problem?

Comment: the file system watcher for instance works only on the first time and the app must be restarted after that, the timer looks like a hack for me because of performance and the third option doesn't work at all sometimes

Comment: Is it a MS-SQL server?

Comment: @AdrianIftode it's MySQL

Comment: @Caddy, I deleted my answer since now is useless. Maybe MySQL has a similar concept of pub/sub for certain queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inter-process communication like this, I would look into TCP/IP Sockets.

[image]

It's a simple, direct way to provide communication between one program and another.  The CodeProject article below will help you get started.

**Further Reading**
[TCP/IP Chat Application Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C)
[PHP: Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)

Comment: Considering he is using PHP he is much better off using something like RabbitMQ and setting up workers of a queue from the C# app.

Comment: @DavidPacker: Why?  Just saying something is true doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: PHP is meant to die after each request, meaning it cannot really (well it can with hacks like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)) hold a persistent connection between the client and the server. This means the PHP script would need to somehow store the currently connected clients (which is unreliable). By asynchronously pushing a durable message to a queue and having the clients consume from it whenever a new message appears you remove the tight coupling between the client and servers whilst keeping the communication. Would the server be Node.js, the AMQP wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @DavidPacker: Your comments really should be an answer. I was going to write the same exact thing as an answer, until I read your comments.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Feel free to do so, Greg. I am here to learn and teach, not for the arbitrary karma points. :) Those are a nice bonus.

Comment: @DavidPacker: I believe the technical term is "Fake Internet Points" :)

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidPacker mentioned in one of his comments, an AMPQ server (like RabbitMQ) is your best bet. It's a publish/subscribe architecture.

1. Your PHP application would publish a message to a certain queue.
2. The C# application would be listening on that queue.
3. Upon receiving this message, the C# application would query the database.

Each instance of the C# desktop application would be connected to the AMPQ server as a subscriber. These would be persistent connections similar to what @RobertHarvey's answer alludes to with his suggestion of using sockets. AMPQ uses sockets, but is a more focused, specific solution to your problem.

I've used this model before in a service oriented architecture with applications written in Java, C# and Ruby.

This decouples the publisher and subscriber, plus it is a technology agnostic messaging system giving you that bridge between technology stacks.